# Running a python .py file on Jetbrain Pycharm

Tags: console, editor, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I write my .py files using  Pycharm JetBrains editors. When I run my codes, the output is shown in a console entitled "Run", without any prompt. Therefore, I dont have access to the variables of my code output. How can I force the pycharm to show the output of my codes in  ipython console?

Comment: What do you mean by "without a prompt"? There is no difference between the pycharm run window and the ipython console output. The ipython terminal is just interactive. Pycharm is for writing full python scripts, not line by line interactive prompts.

Comment: By "without a prompt", I mean I cannot write any thing in the "Run Console". Assume that I write a full python script in which I have defined `x=2`. Then somewhere in the code I set `y=2**x`.  Finally I run my script. Now, where can I obtain the value of `y`?

Comment: You don't. You can `print(y)`, or do anything else with it. As I said, pycharm is not for interactive programming. All variables are cleared before and after running a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the Run Configuration and check the box "Show command line afterwards". This will run your script, but leave you in an interactive prompt. Everything from your script will have been imported and available.

As a note, if you install the IPython package (Preferences -> Project -> Project Interpreter, click + to add packages) then you can get a nicer console interpreter.

Finally, a different way to accomplish what you are looking for: run under Debug rather than Run. You can set a breakpoint and then use the debugger's Console right at the line you might be interested in.